# What the value of a misprinted Graverobber Spider?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, pricing

Could anyone give me an idea on on how much a misprint Magic card could sell for? It's a Graverobber Spider, rarity is uncommon.

Answer (score 3):

Due to their rarity and inconsistency, there isn't really an established market for misprint cards. You may be able to find individual collectors who are willing to purchase misprints, but the value will often depend both on which card it is and how it was misprinted.

Answer (score 2):

As murgatroid says, there isn't a good estimate for any card, but there are a few guidelines. Major misprints are more valued by collectors than little ones, so miscuts where some other card from the sheet is visible are better than off-kilter cuts or shadowed text. More famous or rare cards typically have more demand, because misprint collectors are still collectors, and they still want prominent cards.

From that criteria, I can't give an exact figure for your spider (and especially because I don't know the nature of the misprint), but unfortunately I think I'd have to guess it isn't worth much more than a non-misprinted one.